# How can I have code coverage gutters in Visual Studio Code, but also have working breakpoints?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, code-coverage

I have code coverage working for my Python code in VSCode. However, I can't set or remove breakpoints if the gutters are displayed. This is apparently a [known issue](https://github.com/ryanluker/vscode-coverage-gutters#tips-and-tricks):

> to both use the extension and code debugging breakpoints you need to disable the gutter coverage

https://github.com/ryanluker/vscode-coverage-gutters/issues/288

Is there really no workaround or alternative that doesn't involve turning off the coverage gutter shading?